# How to limit Scanning area within an react-native expo App?

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I am working on a mobile app that should be able to scan a veriety of bar- and qr-codes.
I am using for that purpose the expo-barcode-scanner in combination with react-native-barcode-mask.
The problem is that the user should be able to scan one barcode out of a list of barcodes and right know the app recognizes any barcode on screen. It doesn't matter if the barcode is within or outside the mask.

I tried using different plugins like react-native-camera or react-native-camera-kit. Which contain functions to limit the area the scanner tries to read from. Sadly they are either to old to work or the options just don't work.
Here is a short example how I implemented the scanner.

```
      </View>
        <BarCodeScanner onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
          <BarcodeMask edgeColor="red" animatedLineColor="red" showAnimatedLine />
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                setCamera(false);
              }}
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                padding: 2,
                borderRadius: 100,
                backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0,0)",
                marginRight: 10,
              }}
            >
              <Icon name="close-circle-outline" size={40} type="material-community" color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </BarCodeScanner>
      </View>
```

I haven't found a solution that is up to date and works.
Does anyone know or have an idea how I can limit the area to a smaller rectangle?